# default date remains the same as the date of the process startup if indexed

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, express, mongoose

```
var saleSchema = new Schema ({
  ...
  date: {type: Date, 'default': Date.now, index: true}
 ...
})
```

I tried to put a current date into the database with the data() function but it remains the same as the one already indexed and every next submitted one remains the same as the start up index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could put a `timestamps` flag at the bottom of your schema. That way every time a document is created you will get the creation date - `createdAt`, and every time a document is modified you will get the updated date - `updatedAt`. So for the example model below:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const TaskSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    task: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Please enter a task name"],
    },
    info: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Please provide details for the task"],
    },
    due: {
      type: Date,
      required: [true, "Please provide a due date"],
    },
    complete: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
      default: false,
    },
    createdBy: {
      type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
      required: [true, "please provide user"],
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Task", TaskSchema);
```

In the example above, you can see the timestamps flag is set to true, so when you search for a task document, you will get something like this:

[image]